# What is the azure cognitive services speech to text webhook callback IPs to whitelist?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I need to use azure cognitive services (speech to text) behind a corporate firewall. The speech to text batch processing has a callback from azure notifying once the process is complete.
(https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/batch/csharp) - see webhookreceiver.cs

Does anyone know what azure cognitive services IP addresses that needs to be whitelisted on the corporate firewall so that i can receive the callback requests from cognitive services?

Comment: Can you please add requirements do you have for compliance?

Answer (score 0):

The response from the call has a resultsUrls array, which contains channel_1 and channel_0.  These URL’s are accessible by anyone.
Also, the GET request from step (Make repeated GET https://centralus.cris.ai/api/speechtotext/v2.0/transcriptions/ to find out when the transcription is complete.) that retrieves the list of results is not secured, allowing with the subscription key to view them.

The URI’s / SAS exchanged are only known to you and the service. If those are not distributed further, no one else will have access.
We will have further options like VNET etc in the near future.